# Merging dlls using ILMerge

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, ilmerge

I am trying to merge some dlls into one merge dll using ILMerge.
i have tried several post build commands and nothing worked.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe /lib:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
/lib:”C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies” 
/t:dll /closed /targetplatform:v4,
”C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0″ /out:DataAccessMerged.dll Frameworks.dll ObservableDictionary.dll`

**OR**

placed the macros even of `TargetDir` and so on....

it didnt work.
the .net frameworks is 4 my vs is 2010 sp1.

---

Well guys. I hope this help someone.
The problem is of course frameworks 4, there are several ways to solve this issue.
my way is to create a  ILMerge.exe.config file to the ILMerge exe, and enter this xml

`<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>`

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean when you say "it didn't work"?

Comment: the result is : existed with code 9009 or it loaded nunit GUI app

Answer (score 1):

ILMerge.exe also has a /targetplatform command line option.

For example, `ILMerge.exe /targetplatform:v4`